# Mining pool hardware and bandwidth requirements

Tags: mining-pools

Has anyone measured what are the hardware and bandwidth requirements to run a mining pool? Are there any statistics on that per amount of active miners, their hashspeed and other variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- a good dedicated server will be enough to run a pool like eligius
- you will need to ln -s /dev/null debug.log ( or logrotate the file ) if you dont want to run out of space
- you could use a good anti-ddos protection if your pool becomes popular ( most pools and bitcoin businesses are regularly ddosed .
- concerning server load and bandwidth usage, you could be interested in reading this ( very technical ) [log extract](http://xena.ww7.be/pools.txt) , setting this parameter ( difficulty rewrite ) can help to reduce load ( receiving more or less miners requests / second ) and / or make your pool more or less cpuminer friendly